# Traduction de « the instrument is retained with the works » dans une licence d'utilisation

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, droit-et-justice, art

Je tente de traduire la *[Fair License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_License)* et je bute sur les mots *[instrument](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instrument#Translations)*, *[works](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/works#Translations)* et *[fair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair)*.

Pour se mettre dans le contexte, la *Fair License* est un texte légal (licence d'utilisation) qui permet à l'auteur d'une œuvre de donner des libertés aux utilisateurs. L'œuvre peut désigner un [logiciel libre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logiciel_libre) (*[free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)*), une [musique libre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musique_libre), une photo, une sculpture, un code génétique... Cette licence a pour particularité d'être très concise tout en offrant toutes les libertés possibles dans la limite de conserver ces libertés pour l'*œuvre* et ses *œuvres dérivés*.

Le texte original :

> Usage of the works is permitted provided that 
>   this instrument is retained with the works, 
>   so that any entity that uses the works 
>   is notified of this instrument. 
>   DISCLAIMER: THE WORKS ARE WITHOUT WARRANTY.

Un début de traduction *mot à mot* qui n'est pas très compréhensible :

> L'utilisation des travaux est permise à la condition 
>   que cette notice soit conservée avec les travaux, 
>   afin que toute entité utilisant les travaux 
>   soit informée de cette notice. 
>   AVERTISSEMENT : LES TRAVAUX SONT SANS GARANTIE.

**Est-ce que les anglophones ont autant de mal à comprendre la version anglaise, que les francophones à comprendre cette version française ?**

- *[instrument](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instrument#Translations)* désigne *document légal*, *contrat*, *acte*, *règle(ment)*... Le mot *notice* convient peut être mieux dans ce contexte...
- *[works](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/works#Translations)* fait référence à l'*[œuvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92uvre)* et aux *[travaux dérivés](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Definition#Travaux_d.C3.A9riv.C3.A9s)*.
- *[fair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair)* correspond à *équitable*, *juste*... mais aussi *clair*. Nous pourrions conserver le mot en anglais comme pour le mot *[fair-play](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair-play)* (qui me semble plus usité que *esprit sportif* ou *franc-jeu*).

**Quelles expressions françaises correspondent le mieux aux mots *instrument*, *works* et *fair* dans ce contexte ?**

---

**EDIT**
Traduction avec l'[aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7035/2429) de [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r) et de [Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%c3%a9phane-gimenez)
et des précieux commentaires de [Graffito](/users/8383) et de [Legomononc' blé d'Ingres](/users/3177) :

> Les œuvres peuvent être réutilisées à condition
>   d'être accompagnées du texte de cette licence, 
>   afin que tout utilisateur en soit informé.
>   AVERTISSEMENT : LES ŒUVRES N'ONT AUCUNE GARANTIE.

Comment: Je suis sans aucune formation en droit et il me semble que pour proposer les termes adéquats c'est une nécessité. _Œuvres_ et _clause_ me semble plus adaptés que _travaux_ et _notice_, mais je peux me tromper.

Comment: oui c'est une bonne idée, merci ;-)

Comment: Encore plus simplement: "Les oeuvres [couvertes par cette licence] peuvent être réutilisées à condition d'être accompagnées de cette mention légale".

Comment: Merci @Graffito pour ta simplification de la phrase *"Toute utilisation des œuvres est permise à condition que cette mention légale soit conservée avec les œuvres, afin que tout autre utilisateur des œuvres soit informé de cette mention légale"*. Au niveau de l'idée d'un texte concis nous sommes dans l'esprit de la *Faire License*. Mais peut-être nous nous éloignons trop du texte original. Cela ressemble plus à un résumé car nous ne parlons plus de la raison de la licence: *so that any entity that uses the works is notified of this instrument*. Qu'en penses-tu?

Comment: Je n'avais pas vraiment réalisé que la phrase exprimait en elle-même la totalité des termes de la licence. Je dirai donc: "*Les oeuvres couvertes par cette licence peuvent être réutilisées à condition de mentionner cette licence*."

Comment: J'aimais bien ta première phrase que je complémenterais ainsi : *"Les oeuvres peuvent être réutilisées à condition d'être accompagnées de cette mention légale, afin que tout utilisateur en soit informé"*. Ou cette autre alternative : *"Les oeuvres sont réutilisables à condition d'être accompagnées de cette mention légale, afin que tout utilisateur ait cette information"*. Nous pouvons [relire les motivations évoquées par son auteur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_License#History) afin de coller au plus près de l'esprit original. Merci

Comment: À mon avis le choix du mot _instrument_ était peu avisé par l'auteur. Trop générique, il s'agit simplement d'un truc qui fait état d'une forme de normativité. Il s'agit du texte de _licence_ en contexte ; de la licence comme telle. L'originalité n'est pas de mise ici. La première des deux suggestions du commentaire précédent, est excellente.

Comment: Le problème est que le texte de la licence s'auto-référence : la "mention légale" (instrument en anglais) est le texte même de la phrase. C'est un exercice de sémantique intéressant! Qui aurait une/la solution ?

Comment: Peut-être "Les oeuvres peuvent être réutilisées à condition d'être accompagnées du texte de cette licence, afin que tout utilisateur en soit informé".

Comment: Merci @Graffito pour ton idée :-) Tu proposes de traduire *"this instrument"* par *"du texte de cette licence"*. J'ai l'impression que *"de cette mention légale"* est plus proche du texte original. Après, il vaut mieux être plus proche de l'intention originale de l'auteur plutôt que de sa formulation en Anglais... Qu'en penses-tu ?

Comment: Oui, mais il faut alors comprendre que "cette mention légale" désigne la phrase décrivant la licence.

Comment: Très bonne remarque. Traduction mise à jour :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/nz/deed.fr) utilise *œuvre*, mais n'a pas traduit le texte anglais, à l'inverse de [CeCILL](http://www.cecill.info/licences.fr.html) (licences libres pour les logiciels et **œuvres** scientifiques).

On utilise aussi **mention légale** pour indiquer l'obligation de publier un avertissement obligatoire, *notice* pouvant être rapproché de *guide d'utilisation*.

Quant à *fair*, **équitable** est le plus proche de l'esprit juridique, il s'agit plutôt de respect du fournisseur et de l'utilisateur (comme dans *commerce équitable*), sans qu'il y ait de notion d'*élégance*.

Les traducteurs francophones ont proposé leur choix de traduction sur [le site du projet GNU](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).
Il peut être prudent de livrer à la publication le texte anglais original et sa traduction en français, en précisant que seuls les motifs légaux imposés par la Loi française (Cf. CeCILL) l'emportent sur le texte de référence en anglais.
Même si nous sommes ici dans le « *Fair … with no warranty* ».

> Ces œuvres sont livrées et utilisables telles quelles, SANS AUCUNE GARANTIE, SANS AUCUNE RESPONSABILITÉ FINANCIÈRE des auteurs et des éditeurs.

Encore une fois, une relecture par un juriste français est nécessaire pour être à jour des dernières évolutions juridiques.

Comment: Merci pour ton aide. (Par contre, je n'ai pas trouvé les choix des traducteurs francophones.) Cette licence serait la plus concise des licences libres. Donc, pas besoin d'être exhaustif dans sa version française (l'objectif n'étant pas de se sur-protéger en cas de litige). Bien entendu, les versions anglaise et française seront toutes deux présentes, cette dernière permet juste aux francophones de mieux comprendre. Je demanderai ce soir aux *juristes* de l'[April](http://www.april.org/pique-nique-improvise-ou-presque-le-mercredi-24-juillet-2013) ce qu'ils en pensent. Merci encore.

Comment: @olibre le vrai lien des "faux amis" juridiques : https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/words-to-avoid.html